# Removing php extension from a URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, indexing, anchor

(1) I used the following code in .htaccess to remove php file extension from a URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

(2) I then used anchor tag to index.

```
<a href="../about">About</a>
```

Apache decided to append a forward slash at the end of the URL only to confuse itself.

```
http://localhost:8069/about/
```

(3) How do I remove the forward slash at the end of the URL?

(4) I found an answer here on Stack overflow from 11 years 6 Months ago, it almost solved my problem, the problem is that it left out style sheets and displayed ugly html file.

I tried to remove a file extension from a URL using .htaccess.
A forward slash was appended on the URL.

Comment: "Apache decided to append a forward slash" - This will happen if you also have a physical directory called `/about` on the filesystem. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. I have been looking at php router from phprouter.com
It is working fine for me and requires me to append a forward slash at the beginning of
the path of style sheets especially when the calling php script is in the root directory.
I think this is because of the way the router (router.php) named the index file, it is called forward slash ("/"). 

I will look at the router attentively and understand its deep objective. I also want to know who phprouter.com is, I normally gets motivated when I have these kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a router instead of trying to do this with .htaccess alone. You can try any available free packages, or classes. An example will be:

https://phprouter.com/

I have used this several times, although, I had to do some modications because of how my project is set up. So you might have to do the same, but it's much more flexible and easier to manage than .htaccess.

Comment: Although this is unlikely to resolve the OP's immediate (more fundamental) problem. If they happen to have a physical directory called `/about` on the filesystem then Apache will trigger a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash (thus "breaking" the URL) - this is regardless of whether you have implemented a front-controller pattern (router) or simply using extensionless URLs (as in the OP's case).